How to check if a n equation has rational solution?
For example, how do I know if $(x-y)(x+y)=\frac{7}{2}$ has a solution $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Q}$? I can compute that the solution must be $y=\pm \frac{\sqrt{-7 + 2 x^2}}{\sqrt{2}}$, but how do I  know that there does not exist such an $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $y \in \mathbb{Q}$? Maybe localisation? I tried working $\mod 7$ but I got stuck. Any help would be appreciated!

this is too broad.  in general, it can be extremely difficult to determine if a function in several variables has a rational root.

And $(x+y)(x-y)=7/2$ is a wimpy example.

@lulu   it is related to an indefinite ternary quadratic form  and there are procedures for dealing with it.  Anyway, one answer $\left( \frac{9}{4}, \frac{-5}{4} \right)  $

If variables are more in equation then its difficult to say or prove a given equation has rational solution(in general) .

Is Title is an equation or a n equation ?

@WillJagy  From the header, I assumed the OP was asking about a general function in $n$ variables, of which this was just intended as an example.  In this particular case, you can take any non-zero rational $A$ and solve $x+y=A$ and $x-y=\frac 7{2A}$.  Your point has $A=1$.  But maybe I just read too much into the header.

@lulu  I see what you mean. I thought it had to read "How to check if an equation"  rather than  "How to check if a n equation"

The indefinite ternary quadratic form $ 2 x^2 - 2 y^2 - 7 z^2 $
is visibly isotropic over the integers, namely $x=y$  and $z=0.$  It also has null vectors with $z \neq 0,$  examples include
$$ x = 2 u^2 + 7 v^2 \; , y = 2 u^2 - 7 v^2\; , \; \; z = 4uv  \; . \; \; $$
Taking either $u=0$  or $v=0$  gives $z=0$ and $x = \pm y$
To get your $7/2$  with rationals switch to $u,v \neq 0$  and
$$  x = \frac{2u^2 + 7 v^2}{4uv} \; , \; \;   y = \frac{2u^2 - 7 v^2}{4uv}  $$
giving $$ x^2 - y^2 = \frac{7}{2}  $$
